# Why using inline function in c++ doesn't grow binary size?

Tags: c++, inline-functions

I have written this code:

```
inline int a_plus_b_power2(int a, int b) {
  return (a + b) * (a + b); 
}

int main() {
  for(int a = 0; a < 9999999999999; ++a)
    for(int b = 0; b < 999999999999; ++b)
      a_plus_b_power2(a, b);  

  return 0;
}
```

but why the binary of this program doesn't differ with this program:

```
inline int a_plus_b_power2(int a, int b) {
  return (a + b) * (a + b); 
}

int main() {
  for(int a = 0; a < 9; ++a)
    for(int b = 0; b < 9; ++b)
      a_plus_b_power2(a, b);  

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps show some evidence that they produce the same "binary"?

Comment: Both have inline function!

Comment: Why would it change? at the beginning (I didn't check the assembly, i'm just guessing) it will store the 9 (or 99999 w/e) into a memory location or a register and after that the program are exactly the same.

Comment: I think the OP is expecting the compiler to product 9999999999 * 99999999 (etc) individual explicit calls to the inlined function.

Comment: The first have lots of inline function. they have exact copy of one. so the first would be bigger.

Comment: 999999999999 is a big integer.

Comment: 999999999999 is too big to fit in an int.

Comment: @Inisheer I expect to compiler produce exact 9999999999 * 99999999 individual copy, not calls.

Comment: @Khajavi Yes, exactly what I was referring to, just better stated.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/inline-and-perf.html

Comment: Also, since your result is being ignored, both of these are totally identical to `int main() {return 0;}`, which explains why they're the same size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are confusing function inlining with loop unrolling:

**Loop unrolling** means transforming

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  a(i);
```

into

```
a(0); a(1); a(2); a(3);
```

while **function inlining** means transforming

```
void a(int i) { cout << i; }

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  a(i);
```

into

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  cout << i;
```

Compilers do have options to enable loop unrolling (look at `-funroll-loops` and related options for gcc), but unless you poke them really hard, most of them will be very reluctant to unroll 999999999999 iterations... (the resulting binary would be multiple terabytes).

Comment: It's also not that complicated to do a partial unroll, doing 8 per iteration or something.

Answer (score 2):

Inlined functions are only "pasted" once per invocation.

In both your examples, the inlined function is only invoked once, although it is called many times.

I believe you want something like this:

```
for (unsigned int a = 0; a < 9; ++a)
{
  for (unsigned int b = 0; b < 9; b+= 3) // Incremented by 3 because of 3 calls in loop.
  {
    a_plus_b_power_2(a, b + 0);
    a_plus_b_power_2(a, b + 1);
    a_plus_b_power_2(a, b + 2);
  }
}
```

The above example may cause the compiler to paste the code inside your inline function 3 times within the loop and increase the size of the binary.

*Note:  turn off optimizations because optimizations may cause the compiler to convert the inline function into a standalone function inside the loop.*